# Are Skye and her Father based on characters from the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In "What They Become..." (S02E10), Skye's father mentions that her given name is

> Daisy

and he, himself, is referenced once as

> Cal.

Do these names have any significance or refer to any existing Marvel characters?

Comment: Look, you already knew that.

Comment: Yes, I did. But the point of the site is to share knowledge. I posted the question for people who *didn't* know it.

Comment: Yeah, last night's *AoS* was filled with stuff that non-comics readers aren't going to know.  Perfect opportunity for us to ask questions that help document this stuff.

Comment: Just curious: why the spoiler tags?

Comment: @bluescreen_of_death Everyone has a different tolerance for spoilers. I try to be as considerate as I can within reason. Someone who is well versed in the comics might recognize the names immediately despite not having watched the episode yet and still appreciate the surprise discovery, especially since it only just aired last night.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.  In a [recent interview](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=57656), the showrunners stated (spoilers for *Agents of SHIELD* S02E10):

> **Obviously I wanted to ask about one of the big revelations from the episode -- that Skye is actually named Daisy, and by the end of the episode has powers that certainly appear very similar to Daisy Johnson/Quake from Marvel Comics. It's been clear for a while that there was much more to Skye than originally presented, but was it always the plan for her to be revealed as that character? How did you arrive at that decision?**
>
> **Tancharoen:** That has always been the plan. We are big fans of "Secret Warriors;" Daisy Johnson is a character that we always liked. We always knew there was a potential to evolve Skye into something else. It took a little bit of time, but we were happy when we were able to land on Daisy Johnson, and actually have that work in our mythology.

So, **Skye is Daisy Johnson** from the comics.  Daisy is a superhero code-named Quake with the ability to create and control earthquakes (which we see her accidentally do once her Terrigenesis was complete) and other vibrations.  And she's a SHIELD agent (admittedly in the comics, she's the Director of SHIELD), just like Skye.  In the comics, her father is Calvin Zabo, also known as Mister Hyde.

From [another interview](http://marvel.com/news/tv/23795/debriefing_the_marvels_agents_of_shield_winter_finale#ixzz3LXVAiQIT):

> **Marvel.com: We also get the reveal of her dad as Mister Hyde, or Cal. What does bringing him into the series give you guys?**
>
> **Maurissa Tancharoen**: As we always do, we pulled from what exists in the Marvel Universe and put our own spin on it. We had always had our eyes on Daisy Johnson, and therefore her father and her whole history.

Mister Hyde in the comics is pretty similar to the Hulk.  He's a genius who tried to replicate the fictional Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde serum.  Eventually he succeeds, and  he transforms into a powerful hulking body.  In the show, this is hinted at.  When we first saw Skye's father back in the season one finale, he was covered in blood, presumably from a recent temper tantrum.  When we see him in season two, he is constantly trying to keep his anger in check, which suggests that's the trigger for a transformation.  As revealed in S02E10, his first name can be shortened to 'Cal', which matches 'Calvin'.  So it seems **Skye's father is Calvin Zabo AKA Mr. Hyde**.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really read Marvel comics but I googled the name Daisy Johnson and got this from wikipedia

> Daisy Johnson, also known as Quake, is a fictional superheroine appearing in comic books published by Marvel Comics. Created by writer Brian Michael Bendis and artist Gabriele Dell'Otto, she is a superpowered secret agent of the intelligence organization S.H.I.E.L.D. The character is the daughter of the supervillain Mister Hyde, and has the power to generate earthquakes. A version of the character appears in the television series Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., portrayed by Chloe Bennet.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_Johnson