# Has Skye become Kree?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

Last show of Agents of Shield we get to know that Skye's mother had the anti-aging thingy that Hydra head honcho somehow stole from her.

Skye has touched the object and survived where everybody else died.

Does one simply become alien ( blue one, Kree ) or is she going to turn into a superhero or is there anything in universe that can explain this?

Comment: Related (not dupe): http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/74467/1027

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has been revealed that Skye is in fact Daisy Johnson, a super hero who adopts the Moniker ["Quake"](http://screenrant.com/agents-shield-skye-origin-powers-daisy-quake/)...

The crystals within the Diviner are Terrigen Crystals, which activate the latent abilities of 'Inhumans', who were a race genetically engineered by the Kree (but later abandoned) to Infiltrate earth.

Each inhuman has a different, unique ability.. in the MCU, Quake is revealed to be an Inhuman and this is how she obtained her abilities (demonstrated at the end of the episode). Just like X-Men's mutants, abilities do not neccesarily change ones appearance... so it's likely Skye will remain as she is.

Comment: The real question now is... what has Raina become? Unlike Skye, her appearance definitely changed.

Comment: There is a [Raina](http://marvel.wikia.com/Raina_%28Earth-616%29) character in X-Men, and with the Inhumans being the surrogate mutants of the MCU this would fit nicely... Maurissa Tanchereon [has dropped some heavy hints](http://marvel.com/news/tv/23795/debriefing_the_marvels_agents_of_shield_winter_finale) that Raina isn't going to be elegant anymore, so becoming bestial backs this up

Comment: Well, at least her outside now matches her inside...