# What super-powered character has she become?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In S02E10 of *MARVEL's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*,

> we saw Kree genetic engineering technology at work which transformed Skye and Raina into something different. We also know that [Skye became a comic character Daisy Johnson aka Quake](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/75936/931). When it comes to Raina, we saw her new eyes like an animal of cat family.

Is there a corresponding character in the MARVEL Universe that resembles what she became or has there any official word as to which, if any, established MARVEL character she really is?

Comment: I'm guessing the official statement is probably something like "Wait, and see"

Comment: I heard she was suppose to play "Quake" I tried to track back the source but no result.. thats why its a comment :P

Comment: @Rocket Are you saying Raina was supposed to play Quake, not Skye?

Comment: @SachinShekhar no lol i read this questio  to fast and on my small android lol I thought the question was about Skye. all I could read at 1st was title and 1st sentence lol ... My mistake :S

Answer (score 8):

In [an interview](http://tvline.com/2014/12/09/agents-of-shield-winter-finale-skye-inhuman-daisy-johnson/) with TVLine, Jed Whedon wouldn't give details, only telling people that they will find out in the next episode.

> TVLINE | Has Raina Agents of SHIELD Skye Inhuman been distinctly affected by the transformation as well?
>
> WHEDON | She may have been changed. You glimpsed a little bit of what may have happened to her [at right], but **in the very next episode we learn exactly what happened.**
>
> TANCHAROEN | We know that Raina and Skye have similarities. We seem them both go through the [Terrigen] mist…. Raina absolutely thinks they have a connection are and destined for the same thing. How Raina transforms, you will see in the back half of our season.

Some people are saying she is going to be Tigra.  Tigra isn't an Inhuman in the comics but then neither are scarlet witch or quicksilver.  Everything is just speculation for now.

Comment: As pointed out on a comment I made regarding Raina's fate (on a different question), there is an Inhuman named Raina (maybe Rayna?) who has cat-like eyes, teeth, claws, etc. Very interesting...

Comment: Lol everyone noes [Tigra’s a dood](http://thundercats.wikia.com/wiki/Tygra).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite So is Raina going to become Cheetara?

Comment: @KSmarts: good god, we can only hope so.

Comment: Of course, now that the episode in question has aired, we instead realize that Raina has become Sonic the Hedgehog.